# Comparing term-frequency distributions with unequal sample sizes?

Tags: sampling, information-theory, distance-functions, natural-language

**Background**

I have several datasets of word frequencies where some datasets have much more data than others: from 3000 samples to 20000 samples. I also have large reference corpora with millions of samples.

**Question**

Using term probabilities, I want to compute the pairwise distance between the datasets and the reference corpora to be able to say "Of all corpora, Dataset $A$ is closest to Corpus $S$ while Dataset $B$ is closest to Corpus $P$".

However, I want a metric that will not be overly influenced by the sample sizes of the datasets. For example, if $A$ has 50000 samples, $B$ has 3000, and reference corpora have millions of samples, $A$ might often be closer to the reference corpora than $B$ simply because it has more samples (assuming $A$ and $B$ are similar but not drawn from the same distribution)? I believe that with a naive application of K-L divergence, for example, $A$ would be favored over $B$ but please correct me if this is not the case.

1. What is the best metric for measuring the distance between the term probabilities of a sample and a large corpus?
2. How does unequal sample size affect the metric?